# MySQL 5.1 to 5.5: all UTF-8 characters lost!

Tags: mysql, unicode

I decided to upgrade my Debian installation, and after some days using MySQL 5.5, I found that `mysql` prints garbage to the terminal intead of UTF-8 characters.

I had a look at the SQL file that was produced by `mysqldump`, and noticed it already contained the garbage. Today I dropped the database and got a copy of the old `/var/lib/mysql/database_name/*` which was working well and, to my surprise, I still get the same results.

The file produced by `mysqldump` includes the following lines:

```
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

`/var/lib/mysql/database_name/db.opt` from the old and new databases are the same:

```
default-character-set=latin1
default-collation=latin1_swedish_ci
```

What can I do now? I hope I won't lose the entire database!

**UPDATE**

```
show session variables like 'character%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+

SELECT charset(name), hex(name), name FROM table WHERE id='123';
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| charset(name) | hex(name)                                    | name                       |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| latin1        | 457361C3BA204A6F73C3A92064652053616E74616E61 | EsaÃº JosÃ© de Santana     |
+---------------+----------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
```

The output of name in the last command should be `Esaú José de Santana`

Comment: Please show the terminal's settings.

Comment: Hi, terminal settings have not changed. And the problem is only with MySQL, everything else works: `TERM=xterm; LANG=pt_BR.UTF-8`

Comment: Please show the output of `show session variables like 'character%';`, and of `SELECT charset(mycolumn), hex(mycolumn) FROM mytable WHERE ...` for some affected record.

Comment: Already updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from @CL. helped me a lot with debugging, but it was the other way around: both the database and the backup files were encoded with latin1, but the client expected UTF-8 output.

The solution was to make sure `character_set_client` was set to latin1 as well:

```
[client]
default-character-set = latin1
```

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL output and the terminal work correctly; the problem is that the text in the database is labelled as `latin1`, but actually encoded as `utf8`.

This can be fixed by

1. dumping the database into a Latin1 file, then importing that file as UTF-8:
   [Fixing a MySQL Character Encoding Mismatch](http://alexking.org/blog/2008/03/06/mysql-latin1-utf8-conversion); or
2. in MySQL, converting through `binary` to ignore the wrong encoding:

   ```
   UPDATE table SET column=CONVERT(CONVERT(column USING binary) USING utf8) WHERE id=123;
   ```

   [Fixing column encoding mess in MySQL](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/12/18/fixing-column-encoding-mess-in-mysql/).